# Is a radioactive process describable by survival analysis?

Tags: survival, cox-model, weibull-distribution

According to this [source](https://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c7.pdf), the survival function is defined as

$ S(t) = e^{- \lambda \cdot t} $

while, according to this [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioactive_decay#One-decay_process), the number at time $ t $ of radioactive atoms is

$ N(t) = N_0 \cdot e^{- \lambda \cdot t } $

which is quite the same, or? In general, survival analysis is described as

> Survival analysis is a branch of statistics for analyzing the expected
> duration of time until one event occurs, such as death in biological
> organisms and failure in mechanical systems.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis

I just wonder, why I can't see any hint towards the radioactive decay , nor any assignment of radioactive decay to survival analysis, though I browsed for a while.
Is there something different between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
N_0 e^{-\lambda t}
$$

is just an [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) function. It is not specific for survival analysis, nor is the only feature of survival analysis that consists of many more models and tools than this. At the same time, the function describes a physical phenomenon. It doesn't surprise me why physicists using the simple function won't call it "survival analysis", especially since survival analysis is a model popular in medicine, not physics. I also guess that if physicists used other models and tools that emerged from survival analysis, they would call it like this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. I guess then, that survival analysis is actually "only" about trimming this above simple function..?

Comment: @Ben I'm not sure what you mean. Survival analysis is a whole branch of statistics, with many different models. This is just one of the examples of things used by survival analysis.

Comment: well, so far, I've only seen functions with more and less parameters around the $ e^{- \lambda \cdot t} $ expression, hence my assumption. I mean, given the amount of information out there I definitely have to oversimplify..  however, I'm trying to figure out a denominator and separate those topics (like radioactivity and survival..).

Comment: @Ben don't forget that the survival function for a probability distribution is just [1 minus its (cumulative) distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function#Definition). Your example is perhaps the simplest, but survival analysis allows in principle for any underlying distribution of event times whether or not it involves explicit exponential factors. It doesn't even need to work with a distribution that has a parametric definition--that's a strength of the Cox model that you included as a tag.

Comment: Thank you! I've got another question: In German, survival analysis is called something like "temporal event analysis" which makes me wonder now, whether it could also be used to estimate when I'll win in the lottery? But the events at a lottery do not depend on each other so I guess this (alone?) makes it not being able to be applied by survival analysis? But maybe one could ask "there is a population X, how long does it take until everyone won?" :)

Comment: @Ben for the lottery you need only [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution).

Comment: but could I also use survival analysis? Sorry for those naive questions, I'm trying to put it into the right place in my mind in terms of "makes sense", "doesn't make sense", "should work but over-engineered", "this is geography",..  :)

Comment: @Ben it sounds like a separate question rather than a comment